# Suggestions for distributed task scheduling and Job queue in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, job-scheduling, job-queue

**REQUIREMENT :**

In my project(runs in distributed environment) we have requirement to for a job to be scheduled at fixed time with initial delay of 1 min and it will retry if the job execution failed and it can do a max retry of 10 times with 2 mins delay between each .

**TOOLS WITH WHICH WE CAN ACHIEVE THE SAME:**

I can achieve the same needed functionality with ***`spring-retry`***. But, there are multiple containers available (distributed environment). Tools like `Rabbit-MQ`, `Amazon-sqs`, `Redis-quartz` supports this features. But Im not sure which one is better for springboot.

**FACTORS FOR CONSIDERATION :**

Below are the stuffs that needs to be considered for choosing right tools :

> Distributed environment
>   Consistency
>   Fault Tolerance
>   Ease of configuration
>   Async processing

**QUESTION**

Basically Im looking for something similar to Resqueue and sidekiq ruby implementation equivalent in Java(springBoot). Has anyone achieved the same functionality in their application ? If so , what would be the better choice /way provided with the pros and cons . Suggestions are welcome .

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring's [`RetryTemplate`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/retry/support/RetryTemplate.java), which is easy to configure.

You can use a [`SimpleRetryPolicy`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/retry/policy/SimpleRetryPolicy.java) with a [`FixedBackOffPolicy`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/retry/backoff/FixedBackOffPolicy.java) in your case. 
Max retry attempts can be configured with the `backOffPeriod` property present in the `SimpleRetryPolicy` according to your requirements (2 min in your case).

This retry mechanism is easy to plug into Spring Boot projects.

Comment: Spring retry satisfies the above condition , but it fails miserably when it comes to distributed environment . So, Im looking out for some tools in achieving the same in distributed environment.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives for distributed tasks include

- Raft libs for JVM
- Hazelcast used in CP mode (which uses Raft)
- k8s (which uses etcd)
- spring cloud consul
- dbscheduler
- akka has a singleton